# How do I change my login email?

Tags: support, login

I no longer have access to my email address used to log in to SO, so I need to change this. Even better if I could switch to OAuth with my Google account. How can I do this?

Answer (score 16):

You want to ADD a login, and then - once that's done - remove your current one. You can find basic instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials

Comment: What do you see when you attempt to log in, @greetingsj?

Comment: Ok, this is interesting... Mind [contacting us](/contact) with that error and the email you're using to log in? We just made some changes to this yesterday & might need to work out a few kinks. Thanks!

Comment: I see a ticket about name changes, but not this @greetingsj. I really need to know *which email* you're submitting, since the symptoms you describe are identical to those that would occur using the old email with the new password.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the scenario you're describing, @greetingsj. If you could just send us a list of the steps you took with the email(s) you used at each step (add, recovery, login), it'd help a lot.

Comment: Click [contact](/contact), select "i need to add remove login credentials", continue.

Comment: Why is this not like, just go to your profile, type in your password, type in the new email address, done. Like on every other site? The simple fact that there are multiple questions about this is an indication it is broken.

Comment: Historical reasons, @IvanMcA. We have some plans to make this a bit easier after we've [completely removed OpenID support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ended-on-july-25-2018) from the backend system.

Comment: Here's the new "add login" URL: https://stackoverflow.com/users/login-add

Comment: This helped but don't understand why stackoverflow have made it too complex...?