# Change login email for Stack Exchange (stackoverflow.com)

Tags: support, login, accounts

**How can I change my login email address for Stack Overflow?**

I have added my other email id in stackoverflow.com profile settings. But I am not yet able to login using the new email id. I have to enter old email id and password to log in still.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials

Comment: @NileshRathod - the problem is I have already added the new email. But can't login using it. Do I need to remove the old email id also ?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343112/7666442

Comment: I am not sure where to post it

Comment: I am still facing problem in login. I deleted my old email. Now I am not able to login using my new email and Stack password. But I have to login using gmail. Why ?

Comment: You may want to use the Contact Us link at the bottom of the page (under Company). We can guess, but we're users just like you and don't have access to the systems.

Comment: The orchestration needs to be reviewed; it works, but currently not intuitive. It will be great to have the experience revised and improved.

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me was:

1. Remove your old gmail login by going to `https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/{yourid}` (You can see this if you click on your profile icon > Edit profile and settings > My logins.
2. Sign out of your session.
3. In the sign-in page, enter your new email and click "Forgot password" to get a recovery link.
4. Using the recovery link, set a new password and try logging in with it.

Following these steps helped me detach my gmail and use a different email to login. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why just just go and add the new login using the "add more logins..."-button? And *then* use the new one to login.. *before* removing the old?