# Cannot login with new email address

Tags: support, login

My Stack Exchange account uses an email address for login. Back in December I changed my email address on Stack Overflow. Pretty easy -- or so I thought.

Today I tried logging in to SO from a new laptop. SO kept telling me my password was incorrect. I accessed my account from another machine and found my old email address is still listed, along with my new email address. Here's the My Logins page:

[image: My Logins page]

I can log in with the old email address, but not with the new one. The experience here is confusing. The new email address appears as one of "My Logins", but I cannot log in with it or set a password for it. I cannot make sense of the contradiction.

When I visit "Edit Email Settings", my new email address is listed there. I am not sure if that matters.

I want to log in with the new address, and then get rid of the old one. In that order. What have I done wrong?

It has been suggested I follow another answer, where the process is to remove the old email address, and then hope the new one works. Call me skeptical, but I am not comfortable gambling my account access on that answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change login email for Stack Exchange (stackoverflow.com)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373582/change-login-email-for-stack-exchange-stackoverflow-com)

Comment: That sounds like it might work. Or it might lock me out of my account. If it works, that's awesome. Otherwise, not so awesome. Call me skeptical. As I stated, I would like to login with the new email before deleting the old one.

Comment: What if you skip step 1 in the answer on the dupe but do as advised in step 2, 3 and 4. Use a total different browser.

Comment: Maybe this one https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1847/158100 ?

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery for your new email?

Comment: @rene I hear you. I could have done better due diligence by referencing answers I did not feel addressed my concerns.

Comment: BTW, the account recovery did the trick. Hopefully this can been seen as feedback to the SO team. Invoking "account recovery" on a new email address, without explicit instructions, seems obscure to me. A "change password" link on the My Logins page would have been much more obvious. Or a "confirm email" link, if that was the point. If this same question is asked repeatedly, then perhaps a UX review is in order. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Please write a self answer and accept it so we have a better dupe vote target.

Comment: Did you figure it out? Else I put a description in [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403233/locked-out-trying-to-change-email#comment838694_403233). Do not remove your old login until you have successfully logged in with the new email! :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer for me was similar to this previous similar situation: [Change login email for Stack Exchange (stackoverflow.com)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373582/change-login-email-for-stack-exchange-stackoverflow-com). My bad for not reading the entire answer. In my case, I did not feel comfortable with step #1, deleting my old email address before verifying I could login with the new email address -- and I stopped reading.

After being directed back to the answer, I skipped to step 2 and followed the steps without deleting my existing email address.

2. Sign out of your session.
3. In the sign-in page, enter your new email and click "Forgot password" to get a recovery link.
4. Using the recovery link, set a new password and try logging in with it.

Now I can login with my new email address.

Hopefully this can been seen as feedback to the SO team. Invoking "account recovery" on a new email address, without explicit instructions, seems obscure to me. A "change password" link on the My Logins page would have been much more obvious. Or a "confirm email" link, if that was the point.

If this same question has been asked repeatedly, then perhaps a UX review is in order.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand why this needs to be made so cumbersome. Why not use the [button that is made for the purpose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8a7Qv.png)? The UX you're asking for seems to have already been implemented.

Comment: Please re-read my question. I had already added the new email address. It's behind the blacked-out part of the image with the text NEW EMAIL over it. My question was not how to add the email address. My question was how to login with an address that had already been added.

Comment: Yes, and it's the same solution. When you edit your email under "Edit email settings" (like you did) it appears under "Other" in "My logins". Even if it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU07w.png) you **still** just needs to use the button and then it'll just move up to look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCZpM.png). The reason you need to use the button is that it's not a login at this point. It's just an "Other"..

Comment: I would say that is not obvious. I mean, if you already know that's how it works, then it's really easy to do. I won't argue that. But the text of the button makes it sound like I'll be adding a new email address, not changing the classification of an existing email address.

Comment: That's probably because you can use it even if you didn't change your email address in "Edit email settings". That it makes the email move up is only because it can probably not be in both places at the same time :) But.. I can't say I'm a fan of your Answer here, because it's just not the right thing to do for other users in that same situation.

Comment: Agreed. That's why I suggested a link in the whitespace tot he right of the new email address. Give the link text something that lets the user know they need to take action to enable the email address. "change password", "confirm email address", "allow login with this address", something. The "add more logins" button just sounds like I would be adding yet another way to login: another new email address, or facebook, or google, etc.

Comment: Sure, that would help. Extra information both in the "Edit email settings" and on "My logins".  But why not put the right way to do it in your Answer? Instead of leading users down a "recovery link" path?

Comment: I do not follow. The "right way" is to fix the UX. What makes clicking the "add more logins" button more right than clicking the "forgot password" link at login? And in any case, I have not tried doing it the way you suggest, so I cannot personally vouch that it will work. You may contribute the answer as you please and others may upvote it if they find it useful.